# Android programming using C#

Tags: c#, android, mono

I would like what are the available tools or options that i've in order to create an android application using C#.

I heard about Mono, that is some kind of visual studio made in Java right?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, [Mono](http://mono-project.com/Main_Page) isn't not "Visual Studio made in Java" or anything similar.

Mono in general is a port of .NET (or rather, the underlying specifications) to MacOSX, Windows and Linux.

Additionally, there's [MonoTouch](http://monotouch.net/) which allows you to build iOS applications using C#, and [Mono for Android](http://mono-android.net/) which allows you to build Android applications using C#. With Mono for Android, you typically build your application *in* Visual Studio (or MonoDevelop if you're working on a Mac). Both MonoTouch and Mono for Android are commercial products, whereas Mono itself is free and open source.

Comment: _With Mono for Android, you typically build your application in Visual Studio_  Except if you're on MacOSX because then you most probably would use MonoDevelop.

Comment: It could also be worthwhile to mention that Mono for Android is closed source and that a license is $399.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another one: www.dot42.com

It compiles C# to Android deployable code (dex). It does not require a runtime such as Mono. Currently it supports Visual Studio 2010/2012 Professional. Working on SharpDevelop support.

Disclosure: I work for this company

Comment: There's a huge cliff between the license versions. Deciding to "publish to the play store" a free app will cost me 650 dollars. This is a huge barrier to entry. Even if I wanted to put out a 1 or two dollar app, the barrier is so sufficiently large I wouldn't be tempted to do so. Instead, a volume pricing model would be a more tempting target. Unfortunately, Mono for Android has this same problem so until some product comes that fills this space, them's the ropes. You're missing a big opportunity to be that product.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback and I definitely see your point. Since we are only in tech preview stage, we still have a lot of freedom in terms of the licensing model. Could you elaborate on the volume pricing? What about allowing the community license to publish free apps to the play store? I know it doesn't help the 1 or 2 dollar app, but we also want to avoid having licensees report their revenue.

Comment: Today we revisited the license model. Pro license is down to 399 USD (from 649) and the community license now allows publishing free apps on Google Play.

Comment: That's pretty awesome. Much props to you!